# Dynamics CRM Web API - Assign Records / Update Owner field

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am trying to create a Task record in Dynamics 365 and I want the owner to be a team record for which I have already retrieved the GUID.

This is my JSON and it always fails.

```
{
  "ownerid_team@odata.bind":"/teams(f7e383eb-3966-e711-8122-e0071b66c021)",
  "scheduledend":"2017-07-20",
  "regardingobjectid_new_survey@odata.bind":"new_surveies(f7e383eb-3966-e711-8122-e0071b84b034)",
  "subject":"Amazon SES has suppressed sending to this address because it has a recent history of bouncing as an invalid address.",
}
```

I get a bad request.

Can we not use the Web API to update the owner field of records? I could not find any specific limitations describing the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
"ownerid@odata.bind":"/teams(f7e383eb-3966-e711-8122-e0071b66c021)",
```

Using [Jason Lattimer's CRM REST Builder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder/releases), I've gotten this to work:

```
entity["ownerid@odata.bind"] = "/teams(956B410F-0F6E-E711-810E-00155D6FD705)";
```

One thing to ensure is that the team has a valid security role. You might want to try assigning the team in the UI to make sure the operation works before trying to do it programmatically.